# Spring Integration is not triggering int-http:outbound-gateway URL

Tags: spring-integration

I have the following spring integration configuration which starts from reading a file from drive, transforming it into java object and sending http GET request to a REST APT. The first 2 steps are working fine in my chain, but when it comes to **int-http:outbound-gateway** step, the URL is never triggered nor it is displaying any error message. The application remains running state without showing any error message. It never goes to **kbbCvsReadResponseTransformer** class where I can check the response received from this REST service. What could be the reason. I am using spring-integration-4.1.2

```
<int-file:inbound-channel-adapter id="kbbFileInbound"
        channel="kbbInboundFileChannel"
        directory="file:/ftpguest/kbb-gm-rem/data"
        filename-pattern="GM_Remarketing_Pricing_Res_*.csv"
        auto-startup="true"
        prevent-duplicates="true">
        <int:poller fixed-rate="5000"/>
    </int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>

     <int:chain input-channel="kbbInboundFileChannel" output-channel="kbbCvsReadRequest">
        <int:transformer ref="kbbInputFileDataTransformer" />
    </int:chain>

    <int:chain input-channel="kbbCvsReadRequest" output-channel="cvsVehicleReadRequest">
        <int:transformer ref="kbbCvsUpdateRequestTransformer" />
    </int:chain>

    <int:chain input-channel="cvsVehicleReadRequest" output-channel="cvsVehicleReadResponse">
        <int:header-enricher>
            <int:header name="Content-Type" expression="'application/json'" />
        </int:header-enricher>
        <int-http:outbound-gateway http-method="GET" expected-response-type="com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode"
            charset="UTF-8" request-factory="clientHttpRequestFactory" url="http://services.dev-sea.cobaltgroup.com/inventoryWebApp/rest/v1.0/vehicles/search?vin={vin};inventoryOwner={inventoryOwner}">
            <int-http:uri-variable name="vin" expression="payload.getVin()"/>
            <int-http:uri-variable name="inventoryOwner" expression="payload.getInventoryOwner()"/>
            <int-http:request-handler-advice-chain>
                <ref bean="retrier" />
            </int-http:request-handler-advice-chain>

        </int-http:outbound-gateway>

    </int:chain> 

     <int:chain input-channel="cvsVehicleReadResponse">
        <int:transformer ref="kbbCvsReadResponseTransformer" />
    </int:chain>


    <bean id="clientHttpRequestFactory"
        class="org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory">
        <property name="httpClient" value="#{httpComponentsMessageSender.httpClient}" />

    </bean>

    <bean id="kbbInputFileDataTransformer" class="com.cdk.dmg.kbb.integration.transformer.KbbInputFileDataTransformer"/>
    <bean id="kbbCvsUpdateRequestTransformer" class="com.cdk.dmg.kbb.integration.transformer.KbbCVSUpdateRequestTransformer" />
    <bean id="kbbCvsReadResponseTransformer" class="com.cdk.dmg.kbb.integration.transformer.KbbCVSReadResponseTransformer" />


    <!-- Need to use it from integration-context.xml, there are lot of issues with this file right now, so temporerly copied it here  -->
    <int:handler-retry-advice id="retrier" max-attempts="5" recovery-channel="errorChannel">
         <int:exponential-back-off initial="1000" multiplier="5.0" maximum="60000" />
    </int:handler-retry-advice>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can't help you here without any logs confirmation.

Please, share `DEBUG` logs for the `org.springframework.integration` to have a picture how your messages are traveling.

From other side looks like you have some error there and just send it to the `errorChannel` according to the `<int:handler-retry-advice>` configuration.
And that's why you don't get any reply to the `cvsVehicleReadResponse` after that...

Comment: As I mentioned the console is not displaying any logs, the program continues to be in the running state until I terminate it forcefully. I am running this application standalone from a Junit. I tried to remove the retrier advice completely, still it is behaving the same.

Comment: It doesn't sound good. At least `"Received no Message during the poll, returning 'false'"` DEBUG message you should in logs for each your `5000` for that `<int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>`. From other side we really don't know what all those your transformers do... Please, share DEBUG logs anyway. And yes: try to simplify the use-case to localize the guilty part of the code.

Comment: The transformers are just empty as of now, I am just passing payload from one transformer to another. I really could not find the DEBUG logs anywhere and console is empty.